# Sync file system API in the web

Tags: javascript, web-applications, google-chrome-app

I have a chrome packaged app which saves files with the chrome.syncFileSystem api.
Now I want to develop a web app and fetch these files from the web. Is there a way to do this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Google Drive API to access your Google drive, and you will find the files there. You can discover the location empirically, but, as it is not documented, it could change at any time. Google and others (e.g., Apple) have a habit of moving formerly-easily-visible files into obfuscated places.

To get you started, simply access your Google drive with their UI (web page or Chrome app), and you'll find the synced files. You may have to hunt around a bit with the links on the left of the Google drive web page.

Comment: Rocking - I get a permission error pushing the app to mobile "Permission not recognized by cca: syncFileSystem (ignoring)". Are you certain this is supposed to work or are we talking about different APIs?